# Gradle - Add folder and contents to test resources

Tags: gradle

I want to include a folder *and* its contents in the test resources for a Gradle project.

Let's say I have the following project structure:

```
projectRoot
| - src
|   | - main
|   |   \ - java
|   \ - test
|       \ - java
\ - vars
    \ - *.groovy files
```

The `vars` folder contains several `*.groovy` files that I want to be included in the test resources when the project is built. However, the test resources *must* include the `vars` folder, not just the contents inside that folder.

If I add the following block to my `buid.gradle` file, it only puts the contents of that folder in the test resources:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "vars"
        }
    }
}
```

This makes the `build/resources/test` directory contain the *contents* of the `vars` folder, but not the `vars` folder itself:

```
projectRoot
| - build
|   \ - resources
|       \ - test
|           \ - *.groovy files
| - src
|   | - main
|   |   \ - java
|   \ - test
|       \ - java
\ - vars
    \ - *.groovy files
```

However, what I really am after is this:

```
projectRoot
| - build
|   \ - resources
|       \ - test
|           \ - vars
|               \ - *.groovy files
| - src
|   | - main
|   |   \ - java
|   \ - test
|       \ - java
\ - vars
    \ - *.groovy files
```

(Notice how the `vars` folder is listed in the `build/resources/test` folder)

How do I do this?

Note: I cannot make changes to the directory structure of the project (i.e. the `vars` folder cannot have any sub-directories, and it must be top level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
task copyConfig(type: Copy) {
    from "${project.projectDir}/vars/*.*"
    into "${project.projectDir}/.build/resources/test/vars"
    dependsOn processTestResources
}
copyConfig.mustRunAfter(processTestResources)
testClasses.dependsOn copyConfig
testClasses.mustRunAfter copyConfig
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work. The `vars` folder can't contain any subdirectories. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just re-read the question and noticed this ... will update if I think of a solution for this. I'm wondering if there's a way to use a copy task or something similar. Possibly adding a scripted task to create the dir and copy the files would work

Comment: `taskBeforeCopyingTestSourceSets` is an invalid task?

Comment: sorry - it was a placeholder - updated. see pic above this heading https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout I've attempted to insert the task between processTestResources and testClasses. This maintains your custom resources folder being copied at the same time as the rest of the resources, and before any tests are compiled and run